# CSV Downloaded To Chrome - Error: MIME Type text/csv

Tags: php, google-chrome, csv, mime-types

I am using jQuery to recognise a click on a button which then fires a call to a file:

```
window.location.href = "url";
```

This file queries the database, returns results then writes it to a CSV file. I have the following headers set:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv;');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
```

This works on all browsers except Chrome which returns the following error in the console log "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv: "url"".

The weird thing is that if I call the file directly it works in all browsers.

Code:

```
                $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

                header('Content-Type: text/csv;');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
                header("Expires: 0");
                header("Cache-control: private");

                //Field Headers
                $ncols = oci_num_fields($stid);
                $headers_row = array();
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; ++$i) {

                    $headers_row[] = oci_field_name($stid, $i); 

                }

                while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_NUM+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

                    if(!empty($row)){
                        if(!empty($headers_row)){
                            fputcsv($fp, $headers_row);
                            $headers_row = '';
                        }

                        fputcsv($fp, $row);
                    }

                }

                fclose($fp);                    
                oci_close($conn);
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You are using any the SESSION variable in the query part?

Comment: @KasparMary No, it uses a GET.

Comment: Does chrome not allow the download? In chrome I get this as a warning, not an error. Not sure how to fix it but I can still download my file.

Comment: Three years later, this is still a valid question. Chrome still gives this warning. I get it when using window.location.replace(url) to redirect to a csv file on the click of a button. In my case, the backend is .NET. Like @DonRhummy I just get a warning logged in the developer console but the file downloads fine.

Comment: I feel like a redirect to a file is hacky if you actually want to save it. Did you try the [Downloads API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download)?

Comment: Alternatively, you could try `window.open(url, '_self');`

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=db_1", $username, $password);
    //set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }


$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM csv_filds order by id asc");
$query->execute();
$data = "";
 while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){ 
  $data .= $row['id'].",".$row['Name'].",".$row['father_name'].",".$row['address']."\n";
}
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="csvfile.csv"');
echo $data; exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

header("content-type: application/force-download");

Comment: I am now getting this error: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/force-download: "ur"

Comment: what are you doing next after you setting headers?

Comment: Querying the database, I set the headers pretty much at the top of the file.

Comment: The better way it's to query BEFORE send headers. You can get an error, so you can control it and send headers only after everything is ok. Also, don't you forgot about printing data?

Comment: Ok I moved it right before the output to the CSV, but still gives the same error.

Comment: add Header("Content-Length: ".strlen($output));

Comment: That's not really possible. See amended original post for more code.

Comment: Where do you PRINT your contents? You're sending empty document, as we can see.

Comment: I have a development if I change the javascript call to window.open(url) it also works just not what I wanted as you have to watch a blank screen until its finished!

Comment: The idea is that the .csv file is downloaded to the browser so I use: fputcsv($fp, $row); to print to the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

header("Expires: 0");

header("Cache-control: private");

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but chrome was showing it as a warning rather than an error. I managed to stop the warning showing by changing the header to `'Content-Type', 'text/plain'`.
Pretty annoying that this issue is still around 6 years after op.

Answer (score 0):

Try Application Content Type

> header("content-type: application/octet-stream");

Also User Public access so user can download

> header("Pragma: public");

Answer (score 0):

Try a readfile() of the produced file and add the header "content-length".
If it works then you may have to write to file first and then do the output.